# 'Tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer error

Tags: python

I have a script that is supposed to compare my argument number with two other numbers. If its between them it should return true, if not false

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

obj1 = int(sys.argv[1])
obj2 = (1900, 2100)
def range_check(obj1, obj2):
        if obj1 in range(obj2):
                return True
        else:
                return False

print(range_check(obj1, obj2))
```

I keep on getting "tuple integer error". Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the _full stack trace_ of your error in your question. Please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Helpful links:[How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 3):

When used the way you're trying to use it, the [`range()` function](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?#range) wants *two arguments*: `start` and `stop`, not a single tuple with the two values. There are many ways to give it two values:

1. [Unpack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/) the tuple into two variables by assignment and pass those variables:

```
def range_check(obj1, obj2):
    range_start, range_stop = obj2
    return obj1 in range(range_start, range_stop)
```

2. Index into the tuple:

```
def range_check(obj1, obj2):
    return obj1 in range(obj2[0], obj2[1])
```

3. [Unpack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) the tuple while passing it to `range()` using `*`:

```
def range_check(obj1, obj2):
    return obj1 in range(*obj2)
```

---

Also note:

```
if a == b: 
    return True
else
    return False
```

is identical to

```
return a == b
```

because `a == b` is already `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that the tuple needs to be unpacked. You can do this with the `*` operator like so:

```
import sys

obj1 = int(sys.argv[1])
obj2 = (1900, 2100)

def range_check(integer_value, valid_range):
    return integer_value in range(*valid_range)

print(range_check(obj1, obj2))
```

As noted in another answer, you can omit the broken-out if statement. Also, it is best practice to use arguments that are not variables in the outer scope. This way you don't have any strange behavior with collisions shadowing one another unexpectedly.